# Switch between full names and short names for booktitle in bib

Tags: bibtex

When citing prior work from literature in references, there are two commonly followed formats.

1. Write the full name of the conference or journal
   [image: ref full version]
2. Use a shortened version
   [image: ref short version]

Is it possible to switch between these two formats instantaneously using a flag or something like that? I'm okay to write both formats in bibtex file, but when compiling, only one of them should be picked.

PS: My bib style is IEEEtran. I can't use any other styles.